# How to trigger a url inside anchor tag while opening a accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

Suppose I have the following code:

```
<div id="accordionLeftNav">
    <div class="accordionBox" id="accordionStyle">
        <h3><a href="url">Here</a></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i have the following js

```
if ($("#accordionLeftNav").length > 0) {
    $("#accordionLeftNav").accordion({
        header: "h3",
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true,
        navigation: true,
        active: false,
        icons: {
            "header": "open",
            "activeHeader": "close"
        }
    });
}
```

Now i want to trigger the url inside the anchor tag while opening the accordion.
Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Perhaps, if you watch this event http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate you can get url and do what you want.

Comment: But if you trigger the URL, the browser will change the page, so the accordion is useless, because the page will change anyway, isn't it? What is your goal? Besides, `if ($("#accordionLeftNav").length > 0)` is pointless, you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this. here is the code:

```
if ($("#accordionLeftNav").length > 0) {
            $("#accordionLeftNav").accordion({
                header: "h3",
                heightStyle: "content",
                collapsible: true,
                navigation: true,
                active: false,
                icons: { "header": "open", "activeHeader": "close" },
                activate: function( event, ui ) {
                var headerUrl = ui.newHeader.find('a').attr("href");
                window.location = headerUrl;
            }
            });

        }
```